# Signal fires although dialog not focused

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a dialog with LineEdit elements. I want the dialog to close if ENTER is pressed so I added a slot for the returnPressed() signal:

```
ChPasswd::ChPasswd(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ChPasswd)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->NewPasswordInput, SIGNAL(returnPressed()), SLOT(checkPasswords()));
}
```

At some point I open a message box:

```
QMessageBox mb(...);
mb.exec();
```

The box opens and gets the focus. The problem is that when I press ENTER now, the returnPressed signal in `ChPasswd` fires and `checkPasswords()` is called. Why is this keyboard event handled?

Comment: What is the message box' parent?

Comment: I did. Nothing changed. I also tried to set `mb.setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal)` without success

Comment: Alright, I just figured it out. Since this is a dialog pressing ENTER automatically calls another slot. This slot also calls `checkPasswords()` and therefor created a second message box which appears as soon as the first one was closed.

Comment: @slosd: If you've solved your problem, you should submit it as a self-answer, so that the question doesn't appear to be unanswered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I just figured it out. Since this is a dialog pressing ENTER automatically calls another slot. This slot also calls `checkPasswords()` and therefor created a second message box which appears as soon as the first one was closed.